# Мощный парсер JSON для C#

Tags: json, .net, парсер, c#

Здравствуйте! 
Появилась задача парсить несложные json файлы из .NET приложения. [Ссылка на пример такого файла.](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7486210/pop.txt) мне удалось разглядеть 4 массива: "artists", "tracks", "friends", "albums".
Сам только начинающий программист, подскажите, пожалуйста, нужную библиотеку для доступа к массивам и их содержимому.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну для начала удобный он-лайн парсер, просто, что бы понять структуру: [json.parser.online.fr](http://json.parser.online.fr/)

Ну и сама библиотека для .Net: [json.codeplex.com](http://json.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Как раз то, что нужно!

Answer (score 8):

В .NET 4.0 есть [стандартные средства для работы с JSON](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb907644.aspx). Как вариант - [DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx). Вот пример его использования. Описываете структуры данных:

```
[DataContract]
public class ProfileType
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ProfileTypeIDT { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string SingularName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string PluralName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public ProfileField[] Fields { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class ProfileField
{
    [DataMember]
    public int ProfileFieldIDT { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int ProfileTypeIDT { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string FieldName { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string DataType { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Length { get; set; }
}
```

А потом вот так десериализуете данные:

```
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(jsonString);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(ProfileType[]));
ProfileType[] profileTypes = (ProfileType[])serializer.ReadObject(stream);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Мощные** парсеры:

-ServiceStack Json Parser

-JSON.net