# Каким образом можно заполнять ListView из сложного JSON?

Tags: c#, json, uwp

У меня есть ListView в котором две страницы(Pn и Vt) переключаемые с помощью кнопок. И эти страницы необходимо заполнять из такого JSON

```
  {
  "Pn" : [
    {
      "Number" : "1",
      "Time" : "08:30 - 09:15",
      "Yrok" : [
        {
          "Kb" : "Щелковское шоссе, № 122",
          "Name" : "Музыка"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Number" : "2",
      "Time" : "09:25 - 10:10",
      "Yrok" : [
        {
          "Kb" : "Щелковское шоссе, № 107",
          "Name" : "История"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "Vt" : [
    {
      "Number" : "1",
      "Time" : "08:30 - 09:15",
      "Yrok" : [
        {
          "Kb" : "Щелковское шоссе, № 115",
          "Name" : "Математика"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "Number" : "2",
      "Time" : "09:25 - 10:10",
      "Yrok" : [
        {
          "Kb" : "Щелковское шоссе, № с/з",
          "Name" : "Физ-ра"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Т.е в одном элементе ListView будут выводиться эти переменные

```
"Number" : "1",
  "Time" : "08:30 - 09:15",
  "Yrok" : [
    {
      "Kb" : "Щелковское шоссе, № 122",
      "Name" : "Музыка"
    }
  ]
```

Как это можно попроще сделать? Мне приходит на ум только создать цикл который в котором я буду прописывать каждую переменную, а потом создавать этот элемент типа:  `listView1.Items.Add(itm)`

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/19035/Мощный-парсер-json-для-c
Посмотрите эту ссылку возможно поможет

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как вариант можно сделать так:
Делаем два класса отписывающие наш элемент в json

```
public class Item
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Time { get; set; }
    public List<Yrok> Yrok { get; set; }
}

public class Yrok
{
    public string Kb { get; set; }        
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Далее готовим разметку для связывания:

```
<ListView x:Name="JsonView">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Width="30"  Text="{Binding Number}">   </TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock Width="100" Text="{Binding Time}"></TextBlock>
                    <ListView Width="300" ItemsSource="{Binding Yrok}" SelectionMode="None">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Width="200" Text="{Binding Kb}"></TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock Width="100" Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Теперь осталось десериализовать данные и задать их свойству ListView.ItemsSource.

```
//в data должна быть json строка, той структуры, что вы привели выше
sting data="";
var json = JObject.Parse(data);
List<Item> items = new List<Item>();
foreach (var key in json)
{
   var itm = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Item>>(key.Value.ToString());
   items.AddRange(itm);
}
JsonView.ItemsSource = items;
```

И вот что выходит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А если у меня несколько элементов в Yrok будет? Они разве выведутся все или только первый?

Comment: @Denisok `<TextBlock Width="200" Text="{Binding Yrok[0].Kb}"></TextBlock>
` говорит о том, что выводится первый из списка. Если нужны все, то либо внедрять еще `ComboBox`, или рядом еще лепить `ListBox`, который будет отображать все Yrok у выделенно элемента.

Comment: @Denisok  Исправил разметку, что бы выводились все.