# C# получение массива из строки

Tags: c#, массивы

Доброго времени суток.
Я пока новичок в C Sharp, так что следующий вопрос может показаться банальным. В общем, делаю запрос GET к некому URL, например /version.html. В ответ получаю вот такую информацию:

```
application.VERSION = {
    VERSION: "194",
    BUILD: "19758"
};
```

Собственно, вопрос. Возможно ли преобразовать эту строку в массив? Как считать данные пары "константа : значение"?

Comment: В C# строка сразу разбита на массив.

Comment: Дело в том, что ответ сервера считываю так string HTMLoutput = readStream.ReadToEnd(); т.е. получаю строку. И из нее нужно получить данные в виде массива

Comment: Опишите в каком именно виде вы хотите видеть массив? Массив чего вы хотите видеть? И чем вас не устраивает массив char? При разборе  ответа  лучше использовать объект HttpWebResponse.

Comment: Может я неправильно сформулировал вопрос. Задача состоит в том, чтоб из plain-text ответа сервера (сам ответ в вопросе) получить значения VERSION и BUILD для сравнения актуальности версии. Что можно сделать с подобным ответом от сервера?

Comment: По сути ваша задача сводится к парсингу формата JSON. Посмотрите вот [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/19057/222168) на этом сайте, или [этот](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/19038/222168).

Comment: Коллеги, присмотритесь. Это не JSON :)

Answer (score 5):

Это у вас [JSON](http://json.org/). Так что используйте любую библиотеку для работы с JSON, какая вам понравится. Приблизительно вот так может выглядеть решение на [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

namespace Test
{
  static class Program
  {
    private static void Main()
    {
      string input = "application.VERSION = { VERSION: \"194\", BUILD: \"19758\" };";

      // Обрезаем всё, что за пределами фигурных скобок, иначе Json.NET не съест строку.
      input = Regex.Match(input, "{.*}").Value;

      // Создаем объектовую модель из строки.
      JObject jo = JObject.Parse(input);

      // Теперь можно обращаться к полям JSON-объекта по именам.
      Console.WriteLine("Version = " + jo["VERSION"]);
      Console.WriteLine("Build = " + jo["BUILD"]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Как верно заметил @eastwing в комментариях к вопросу, мы имеем дело не совсем с JSON'ом. У нас тут ключи не взяты в кавычки. Так что говоря строго, мой ответ неверен. Но Json.NET почему-то успешно схавал предложенную строку, и пример кода работает. Наверное, не буду пока удалять ответ. Может кто-то прокомментирует, почему всё отработало. Возможно кавычки не являются обязательными, например.

Comment: [JavaScriptSerializer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) тоже успешно съедает строку после обрезки. Хотя да, ключи должны быть в кавычках.

Comment: да, подтверждаю. даже без кавычек в ключах - работает. Единственное, не хочет отрабатывать, если присутствуют переносы строк, поэтому пришлось делать input = input.Replace("\n", ""); перед вызовом Regex.Match

Comment: @Hicks: У Json.NET есть режим, когда он не требует кавычки (это конфигурируется). А вот замена `\n` должна была быть не нужна.

Answer (score 4):

Приведённый текст хоть и похож на JSON, но всё же им не является.

Как вариант, можно использовать регулярное выражение.

```
string input = "application.VERSION = { VERSION: \"194\", BUILD: \"19758\" };";

string pattern = @"(\w+) : \s+ "" (.+?) "" ";

var matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

foreach (Match m in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Name: " + m.Groups[1].Value);
    Console.WriteLine("Value: " + m.Groups[2].Value);
}
```

Comment: тоже рабочий вариант. Но почему-то не хочет отрабатывать значения, в которых есть точки, напр. string input = "application.VERSION = { VERSION: \"1.9.4\", BUILD: \"19758\" };"; уже не сработает

Comment: @Hicks - поправил регулярку. Теперь и с точками будет работать.

Answer (score 1):

Для работы с JSON в C# есть несколько вариантов. Здесь это неплохо описано https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620165/how-can-i-parse-json-with-c. Если вкратце - то хорошо для этих задач подходит Json.NET http://www.newtonsoft.com/json. Вот пример с их сайта как десериализовать JSON(правда в класс, а не в массив). Естественно должен быть класс с полями с такими же именами

```
string json = @"{
  'Name': 'Bad Boys',
  'ReleaseDate': '1995-4-7T00:00:00',
  'Genres': [
    'Action',
    'Comedy'
  ]
}";

Movie m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Movie>(json);

string name = m.Name;
```

Comment: стоит добавить основное из ответов по ссылке

Comment: Grundy, по моему как то так)